# Azure Virual Machine stops after sometime

Tags: python, windows, azure, azure-devops, azure-virtual-machine

I have a Windows azure virtual machine. I am running python process on it. When I disconnect remote desktop. My process runs for sometime and stops after sometime. When I remote login again I can see that my process is no longer running. When I run same process on my local machine it keeps running. So problem is with Azure machine.

I have verified that my machine is not shutdown. Its status is always running. I have 4 core, 16GB machine to resources constraint are also not there, my python process is very small.  I have auto shutdown off.

I have a requirement that I need to Windows only so using option of ubuntu is not there.

What can be the problem here?

Comment: Don't run it as user process, run it as a service.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I didn't get it.

Answer (score 1):

You are running the process in the context of a user session of a logged on user.

When you disconnect the process continues to run since the user session is still running.

Eventually it hits a time limit for how long a disconnected session continues to run. When this happens the session is terminated and your program stops running.

Running this process as a windows service would solve it.